# Possible Duplicate user

Tags: discussion

Looks like this user created 2 accounts (same day, today):

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/47575/zostalesfdc

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/47574/zostale

and now edited his own [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185861/approval-process-for-master-detail-records)