# Creating A Duplicate Account On New Account Creation

Tags: bug

I do not know if this is the place to pose a possible bug and as I am super new to Stack Exchange (honestly any forum for that matter) I apologize if this out of place.

A couple days ago I posted a question anonymously (as a guest) and then was prompted to create an account if I wanted to edit my post. Doing this created a second account even though it was under the same email. My accounts were created very close to one another (based on my user_id for each account). I did not make two intentionally.

[Possible Duplicate user](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/possible-duplicate-user)

Referring to the question above as it is possible that it is similar to my experience. It appears to me that user **Zostalesfdc** may have had the same issue I did when creating a new account considering their user_id's are only 1 apart. I may be wrong but it caught my eye.

It's possible the ability to allow many accounts to share one email is a bug when dealing with a guest account turned new account or maybe it's an intentional association but it's very easy to create two accounts accidentally this way.

Answer (score 1):

As I advised you on your own question, use the [contact us](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) link to request the accounts be merged. It's pretty quick to clean up. :)

Comment: Oh I did !  And yes, was a very quick and easy fix :) . I just thought it should be pointed out as something that could be improved on so others (like yourself) don't have to spend your time hunting those issues down.

Comment: Yeah I wonder why the UI is so confusing. I haven't done it myself. Maybe they just consider anonymous askers a bit of an edge case.